# How to convert 2d product packaging net to 3D mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, packaging

I've been asked to design some product packaging and have been supplied the 2D net file. Is there some software that can convert the net into a 2D mockup of the 3D box, so my customers can see what the design looks like as if the flat-pack net had been bent into shape.

Answer (score 1):

if it's a simple box, you should be able to use the 3D features in Photoshop Extended to make one and texture it using the design you have, but it the design is more intricate, you might need to use a 3D editor (Sketchup,Blender,Wings3D,etc.) to fold your 2D design into a 3D model. At this stage you can choose to render a visualization in the 3D tool of your choice or import in Photoshop.

Alternatively you could use a commercial plugin in Illustrator like [FoldUp!3D](http://www.comnet-network.co.jp/eng/product/NEWFoldUP3D.html) or [Origami](http://boxshot.com/origami/) which seem to do what you're after.

[image: foldup!3D plugin]

[image: origami plugin]

Answer (score 0):

Most 3D software can import images that you then UV map to 3D objects. Some have improved support for things like EPS files. [Shade 3D](http://mirye.net/shade-3d) lets you import EPS files directly into a scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to fake it, the website [psdcovers](http://www.psdcovers.com/) has pretty good actions for seeing a 3d representation quickly.